# Filter results with date range with php

Tags: php

i'm fetching data from a web `API` which then returns data. From the data received i'm trying to apply a filter which searches between dates and display results but i'm finding it hard to do.

From the data recieved from the api, it contains a data with date `'2017-02-28T00:00:00Z';` when you specify the start_date variable like this `$sdate='2017-01-28T00:00:00Z';` and the end_date variable like this $edate='2017-02-28T00:00:00Z'; you get the data returned.

When you specify it like this `$sdate='2017-01-28T00:00:00Z';` and the end date as this `$edate='2017-03-28T00:00:00Z';` it bring out no data.

```
$baseURL = 'https://myip/DynamicsNAV90/WS/';
$pageURL = $baseURL.rawurlencode($cur).'/Page/info';

$id='0101001';
$sdate='2017-01-28T00:00:00Z';
$edate='2017-03-28T00:00:00Z';
$error_msg=array("message"=>("Bill not found"));
//echo $sdate;
$params = array('filter' => array(
                                array('Field' => 'ID', 'Criteria' => $id),
                                array('Field' => 'Date', 'Criteria' => $sdate),
                                array('Field' => 'Date', 'Criteria' => $edate)
                                ),
                    'setSize' => 0);
$result = $page->ReadMultiple($params);
$customers = $result->ReadMultiple_Result->BillingInfo;

if ( $customers->Date >= $sdate && $customers->Date <=$edate)
{
    echo json_encode(array($customers));
}else{
    echo json_encode($error_msg);
}
```

what i'm trying to do is to search in between, i could have done this by writing a select statement on the database and specify the date ranges but since i'm only pulling from a web api its really difficult

Comment: What is the web API that you are using?

Comment: included it now in the edits